# MySQL Select* returns everything but the id column

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 tables I wish to pull data from both and display it in an html table. When I execute the below select statement I seem to get everything but the auto_increment column "id"

```
>mysql connection strings here.

$query = "SELECT Hotels.*,surfcup_Rates.*
          FROM Hotels 
               LEFT JOIN surfcup_Rates
               ON Hotels.id=surfcup_Rates.hotelID";
```

Then I use load the query into $result.
Later I load it into mysql_fetch_array and loop it into an html table.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo '<a href="DeleteHotelRecord.php?id="['.$row['id'].']">Delete</a>';
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['preferred'];
>and so on...........
```

Everything works: the join, the select statement and data loads into the table
perfectly. All except the `id` column from the first table. I wish to use the `id` to allow the user to delete a record. The user will be adding data to the tables from a password protected "back-end" for data entry.

Is there something wrong with my select statement? Or am I missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You, 
Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `surfcup_Rates` table also have a field called `id`? If so, mySQL won't know what`id` to use, `hotel` or `surfcup_Rates`.

In this case you have a couple of options,

1. changing the table structure, but do so at your own risk as other things could break
2. use an alias (best method)

**DISCLAIMER**

I have never used the following method in PHP myself, I have seen it in SAP and Zimbra, as this isn't a discussion forum on these aspects, instead of a debate I thought I would put a disclaimer that it may not work but as mentioned above and in my comment below I have seen it work

1. call `hotels.id`

I hope this helps

Comment: #3 isnt correct... that only solves an issue with ambiguous columns on the mysql side. The result set in PHP is still going to only have one ID column if hes reading it via associative (column name) keys instead of position keys (indexed integers). 1, and 2 are viable though, 2 being the most "proper" IMO and with the least amount of effort.

Comment: @prodigitalson, thanks for the comment and I agree #2 is the best but, if number 3 isn't correct, then could you please explain how this works in a `WHILE` statement, it comes directly from a production "Enterprise Suite" that is extremely popular in the corporate world, it runs without errors or any problem and outputs perfectly: `$model_name = $model_data['models.modelName']` - I'm not the developer of the software, I just do enhancements on the package, I have seen it in a number of other "Enterprise applications" also, so would appreciate knowing how it does work... cheers

Comment: @prodigitalson, if you know how it works based on your comment I would appreciate the answer but if not I put a disclaimer and the applications I have seen it working in with my answer. Cheers

Comment: using `table_name.column_name` works on the DB side for disambiguation in a clause like `ON`, `WHERE`, etc. But thats not the problem hes having hes got that down. The problem hes having is in referencing things via associative array in PHP. Given that array keys must be unique you can run a join and expect the assoc array coming back based on the row to have two of the same key. Therefore you have to make the final row repesentation returned by the query have unique column names otherwise the last column in the row with that name will override all the others in the array.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to use an alias as you and others have suggested. As far as the software youre talking about that may be something it does internally with its data access layer. Ive made a number of simple ORMs and DBALs that handle this automatically because internally they either do everything based on column position or they automatically alias every column in the query. I suspect the tools your using use one of those strategies as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Since this is in it's beginning stages It was very easy for me to change the 'id' column name in surfcup_Rates table. Naming two columns the same in 2 tables was a dumb error, I should know better. Thanks again At the risk of wearing out my welcome I now display the 'id' column data from the Hotels table. But the delete link string is not picking up the 'id'.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help. A good practice is to prefix both table and column names, it makes it easier to ensure you have unique identifiers on each column, for example standard abbreviations like wx for weather and co for company work wonders, this should avoid such problems in the future. Good luck with your application

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM Hotels  
LEFT JOIN surfcup_Rates 
ON Hotels.id=surfcup_Rates.hotelID";
```

NOTE: I would probably do all the fields in the select

```
SELECT Hotels.id as HotelId, surfcup_Rates.id as SurfCupId,....
 [others here] ... FROM Hotels  
    LEFT JOIN surfcup_Rates 
    ON Hotels.id=surfcup_Rates.hotelID
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `surfcup_Rates` table has an `id` column (you don't say that explicitly, but it seems likely), then you either need to "rename" one of the `id` columns from the two tables so they don't collide when `mysql_fetch_array` figures out what to return for each row, or I believe you can just swap the two parts of the `SELECT` output selectors, given that you don't seem to care about the `id` from the `surfcup_Rates` table:

```
$query = "SELECT surfcup_Rates.*,Hotels.*
FROM Hotels 
LEFT JOIN surfcup_Rates
ON Hotels.id=surfcup_Rates.hotelID";
```

In this case, the `id` from `Hotels` will mask the one from `surfcup_Rates`, not the other way around as you have it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Since this is in it's beginning stages It was very easy for me to change the 'id' column name in surfcup_Rates table. Naming two columns the same in 2 tables was a dumb error, I should know better. Thanks again At the risk of wearing out my welcome I now display the 'id' column data from the Hotels table. But the delete link string is not picking up the 'id'.